# EntityType - Can not use query_builder

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have a problem with my FormType in Symfony. I have a field that allows me to check one or more checkboxs whose values represent objects from another entity. (In this case, types of holidays).

Except that I do not want to display them all, so I use a `query_builder` as such:

```
->add('typesConges', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => TypeConge::class,
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (TypeCongeRepository $repoTypes) {
                    return $repoTypes->getTypesNotNull();
                }
            ])
```

But it raised this error :

> The name "Heures supp" contains illegal characters. Names should start
>   with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits,
>   numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

However, if I remove the `query_builder`, I have all my `TypeConge` ( the "Heures supp" aswell).

**GestionSoldes.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

class GestionSoldes
{

    /**
     * Types de congés
     *
     * @var Collection|TypeConge[]
     */
    private $typesConges;

    /**
     * All types
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $allTypes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->typesConges = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|TypeConge[]
     */
    public function getTypesConges(): Collection
    {
        return $this->typesConges;
    }

    public function addTypesConge(TypeConge $typesConge): self
    {
        if (!$this->typesConges->contains($typesConge)) {
            $this->typesConges[] = $typesConge;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTypesConge(TypeConge $typesConge): self
    {
        if ($this->typesConges->contains($typesConge)) {
            $this->typesConges->removeElement($typesConge);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAllTypes(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->allTypes;
    }

    public function setAllTypes(bool $allTypes): self
    {
        $this->allTypes = $allTypes;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Form:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\TypeConge;
use App\Entity\GestionSoldes;
use App\Repository\TypeCongeRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;

class GestionSoldesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('typesConges', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => TypeConge::class,
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (TypeCongeRepository $repoTypes) {
                    return $repoTypes->getTypesNotNull();
                }
            ])
            ->add('allTypes', CheckboxType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Tous les types de congés',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-control-label',
                    'for' => 'allTypes'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-control-input',
                    'id' => 'allTypes'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => GestionSoldes::class,
        ]);
    }

}
```

**My repo function:**

```
/**
 * Retourne les types de congés qui ont un solde initial différent de null ( pour form EntityType )
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function getTypesNotNull()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.soldeInitial is not null')
        ->orderBy('t.nom', 'ASC');
}
```

Comment: What the query returns? It should return the query builder, not the actual result

Comment: It returns just the constructor. I don't use ->getQuery()->getResult()

Comment: With the provided info I don’t really think that the issue is with the form type. It should be either with the data which the query returns /it’s formatted strangely/ or with the form rendering..

Comment: I updated my first post with all the code I use for that. I don't think that I've any problem at this level :/

Comment: this kind of error happens to appear, when the form builder's `add` method is called with an invalid field name `$builder->add('something invalid',...)` (a space in the name for example). at least, that's what I know your error message from...

Comment: No, it can not be that because I'm doing ```add->('' TypesConges '') ``` and it exists. When I do not use the query_builder, it works. Can it come from the fact that in my ``` GestionSoldes ``` class, my variable ```$ typesConges``` is ```Collection | TypeCongress [] ``` ?

Comment: I succeeded ... I did the query directly in the "query_builder". Except that when I put -> orderBy ('t.name', 'ASC'), it gives me the error, while I have a field "name" in my TypeCongue.php, too bad ...

Answer (score 0):

As it shows no errors when you remove te `query-builer`, The problem must come from the query-builder.

As the only moment you use the property `nom` in the `query-builder` is in

```
->orderBy('t.nom', 'ASC');
```

The problem is here.
Make sure that your ORM (doctrine or else) is ok with string containing spaces.

> to verify my point try to remove the `orderBy` from your query